# I need to add one more slide to the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

I need to add one more slide to the slider. I tried creating this in fiddle  but could not. You can save it in a editor and run it and see how it works.

I already have 2 slides working on the page but could not get another slide added. When I add code for another slide the slider stops working. You can copy paste the slide code and see it gives issue. I believe it is something with the jQuery code on the page which needs some tweaks.

Please help.

Thanks!

```
  <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
    <title>Zones: Connecting Businesses and Technology</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/3214/1d/www.zones.com/images/css/global_v4.css"/>
    <script src="http://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/3214/1d/www.zones.com/scripts/libs/jquery-v1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/3214/1d/www.zones.com/scripts/libs/modernizr.min_76f186e89c0fb7aea21b6651c289f239.js"></script>
    <script src="http://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/3214/1d/www.zones.com/scripts/jquery.placeholder_55351e456a0735663fd3574e21838fb.js"></script>
    <script src="http://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/3214/1d/www.zones.com/scripts/zones_24172738c15b438acb5bcd07c089eee0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/3214/1d/www.zones.com/scripts/global_daf680176b016ace5457c1c16126c23d.js"></script>
    <!-- zones.js redesign replacement -->
    <script src="http://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/3214/1d/www.zones.com/scripts/showoff_0a6c88755a7faf1f7d0c7fbbbc51bdba.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/3214/1d/www.zones.com/scripts/homeslider.js"></script>

    <!--Banner slider-->

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="headerWidth">
    <style>
    .section-solutions { background-color: #fff; }

    .section-healthcare { padding-top: 40px; }

    .section-links { padding: 15px 0px; }

    .section-partners { padding: 70px 0; }

    .section-products .products-hero div { line-height: 30px; }

    .section-brand-statement { height: 55px; }

    .section-brand-statement h1 {
      line-height: 55px;
      font-size: 26px;
    }

    .section-products {
      background: url('http://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/3214/1d/www.zones.com/images/css/home_tile_split_bg_20140723.png') repeat-x;
      padding-top: 43px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0;
      height: 335px;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding-bottom: 25px;
      background-color: #e9e9e9;
    }

    .slider-bg {
      background: url('http://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/3214/1d/www.zones.com/images/css/home_tile_split_bg_20140723.png') repeat-x;
      height: 378px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .cf:before, .cf:after {
        content: " "; /* 1 */
        /*display: table; /* 2 */
    }

    .cf:after { clear: both; }

    /* For IE 6/7 only: Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats. */
    .cf { *zoom: 1; }
    </style>
    <div id="main-content"> 
      <!--BEGIN HOMEPAGE--> 

      <!--END SECTION--> 
      <!-- BEGIN SECTION-->
      <div class="slider-bg">
        <div class="home-section section-healthcare">
          <div class="inner-arrow"> <a href="" class="homeSlideLeft" style="display:none;"><img src="http://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/3214/1d/www.zones.com/images/css/arrow-slider-left_20140529.png" alt="Slide Left"></a> <a href="" class="homeSlideRight"><img src="http://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/3214/1d/www.zones.com/images/css/arrow-slider-right_20140529.png" alt="Slide Right" style="float:right;"></a> </div>
          <div style="width:10000px;">
            <div class="inner-slide" style="margin-left: -900px;">
              <div class="right"> <a href="http://www.zones.com/site/statics/static_page.html?name=zones/retail-solutions"><img src="http://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/3214/1d/www.zones.com/images/css/products-retail_20140724.png" /></a> </div>
              <h3><a href="http://www.zones.com/site/statics/static_page.html?name=zones/retail-solutions">Zones retail solutions</a></h3>
              <p class="p"><strong>Make connections that drive transactions.</strong><br />
                <br />
                Zones fills the retail space, from the digital signage and mobile point-of-sale to inventory management.</p>
              <p><a class="link-transition" href="http://www.zones.com/site/statics/static_page.html?name=zones/retail-solutions">View retail solutions <span class="orange">&raquo;</span></a></p>
              <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="inner-slide">
              <div class="right"> <a href="http://www.zones.com/site/statics/static_page.html?name=healthcare/micro/zones-healthcare"><img src="http://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/3214/1d/www.zones.com/images/css/products-healthcare_20140724.png" style="margin-top: 10px;" /></a> </div>
              <h3><a href="http://www.zones.com/site/statics/static_page.html?name=healthcare/micro/zones-healthcare">Zones healthcare solutions</a></h3>
              <p class="p"><strong>Keep moving healthcare forward.</strong><br />
                <br />
                Zones experts ease the convergence of new technology and healthcare.</p>
              <p><a class="link-transition" href="http://www.zones.com/site/statics/static_page.html?name=healthcare/micro/zones-healthcare">View healthcare solutions <span class="orange">&raquo;</span></a></p>
              <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- BEGIN SECTION--> 
      <!--END SECTION-->
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://a248.e.akamai.net/f/248/3214/1d/www.zones.com/scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
       $(".homeSlideLeft, .homeSlideRight").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var max = $(".inner-slide").length;
        var first = $(".inner-slide").first();
        var width = 900;
        var margin = parseInt(first.css("margin-left").replace("px",""));
        var index = Math.round((margin * -1) / width) + 1;
        var direction = $(this).attr("class").indexOf("Left") != -1 ? "left" : "right";

        //console.log("max >> " + max);
        //console.log("index >> " + index);
        //console.log("direction >> " + direction);
        //console.log("margin >> " + margin);

        if (direction == "left"){
          var newMargin = (margin - width) + "px";
          first.animate({"margin-left": newMargin}, {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'easeInOutCubic'
          });
        } else {
          var newMargin = (margin + width) + "px";
          first.animate({"margin-left": newMargin}, {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'easeInOutCubic'
          });
        }

        if (index == max){
          $(".homeSlideRight").hide();
          $(".homeSlideLeft").show();
        } else {
          $(".homeSlideRight").show();
          $(".homeSlideLeft").hide();
        }

        return false;
      });
    });
    </script>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please explain what change you made to add another slide. Showing us a wall of markup doesn't do that.

Comment: Create  a working demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: I tried adding it in fiddle but did not have success. sorry about that

Comment: Isherwood - I added another set <div class="inner-slide"> and tried running it.